# Eclipse / Zend Studio CSS Classes and ID's autocompletion

Tags: css, eclipse, autocomplete, zend-studio

I'm using **Zend Studio** for my PHP projects, it's simply perfect for PHP development but sometimes I need to go out from Model and Controller and **deep into Views** (*.phtml files in my case).

I successfully enabled the Javascript autocompletion in the whole workspace and I installed the jQuery support for jQuery autocompletion, i found HTML autocompletion built-in.

Now the question is: **How can I enable CSS classes and Ids autocompletion in Zend Studio?**

Imagine that you have a **.css** file with all your css classes/ids and you want to use the class `makeItBig` in a **div** .

The div before:
`<div> Your big content </div>`

The div after:
`<div class="makeItBig"> Your big content </div>`

How can you obtain the **autocompletion** while typing the class name without have to open the css file to look for the exact name of the class?

P.S : *I don't intend to switch to another Editor.*

P.P.S *I'm using Zend Studio 10 on Mac OSX Mountain Lion*

Comment: as much I know , you can not have auto-completion for user defined values. rather you can have html element tags and attributes only.

Comment: I am using zend studio version 11, and I have same issue. php autocomplete working perfectly but css and html not working